# Empty ICommand and IQuery interfaces when implementing CQRS

Tags: oop, interface, cqrs, object-oriented-analysis

I've been reading about CQRS and was googling for some examples. In this process I have found the [GitHub repo for the Pluralsight course "CQRS in practice"](https://github.com/vkhorikov/CqrsInPractice/tree/ce5be7233a83b8dec1bcb3461d9ebf58d2aaf1de) (unfortunatelly I can't get access to the course right now). I was looking at the source code and then I have noticed something that I felt awkward at first: there are two interfaces `ICommand` and `IQuery` which are simply *left empty*. In other words:

```
public interface ICommand { }
public interface IQuery<TResult> { }
```

After that all commands will implement `ICommand` and all queries will implement `IQuery<TResult>`.

But this is awkward for me. An interface is a *contract*. A class implementing it will sign to contract and will be guaranteed to have the specified methods. There is no method here whatsoever. So I really don't see why anyone would do that.

So what is the point of having a blank interface? Why would anyone create and implement interfaces which do not define any contract?

Comment: It's the marker interface pattern. It just tells you which concrete classes are expected to be used as `ICommand` for instance. You'd usually have `IHandleCommand<T extends ICommand>`. You can sometimes use annotations instead of marker interfaces for this, but you can't have generic types constrainted on annotations in most languages (perhaps all) I believe.

Answer (score 1):

A good reference here is *Effective Java*, by Joshua Bloch:

> Use Marker Interfaces to define types
>
> A *marker interface* is an interface that contains no method declarations but merely designates (or "marks") a class that implements the interface as having some property.

Because the marker interface defines a type, you can use the type checker to catch certain categories of errors at compile time rather than at run time.

Bloch suggests a particular question: "Might I want to write one or more methods that accept only object that have this marking?"

In the DDD case, would you ever want to write a method that only accepts ICommand or IQuery?

After a quick scan of Khorikov's example, it is not obvious to me that he needs to define a type - an annotation, or even a comment, might be a better choice.